# React Select IE 11 - TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'

Tags: react-select

What is wrong with this code ...IE 11 throwing 
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'...chrome is behaving fine

```
import React from 'react';

import Select,{components} from 'react-select';
import { colourOptions } from '../react-select_Samples/data.js';

const Option = props => { 
    return ( <div>
        <components.Option {...props}><input type="checkbox" checked={props.isSelected} onChange={() => null} />{props.label}
        </components.Option></div> ); 
    };
export class SampleDropdown extends React.Component {
    render() {       
        return (
            <Select
              className="basic-single"
              classNamePrefix="select"
              defaultValue={colourOptions[4]}
              isSearchable
              name="color"
              options={colourOptions}
              components={{ Option}}              
              hideSelectedOptions={false}
              isMulti
            />
        );
    }
}
```

here is package.json  ...
it has following packages
"bootstrap(^3.4.1), es6-promise-promise(^1.0.0), react(^16.8.6), react-bootstrap(^0.31.5), react-dom(^16.8.6), react-router-bootstrap(^0.25.0), react-router-dom(^5.0.0), react-scripts(3.0.0), react-select(^2.4.3), rimraf(^2.6.3), whatwg-fetch(^3.0.0"

```
{
  "name": "reports_react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "es6-promise-promise": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0",
    "react-select": "^2.4.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the contents of the `package.json` and your Babel configuration?

Comment: Added in my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the React app is being build (dev or prod), [spread operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) are being transformed into `Object.assign` assignments.

A solution would be to use the `babel-polyfill` package and import right at the top of your entry point (`index.js` by default) to ensure correct functionality.

---

Another solution is to eject your react app using `yarn eject`, which will allow you to configure the build procedure of your app. You might have to delete the `node_modules` folder and reinstall your packages.

After ejecting you have to install the `@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign` package using `yarn add @babel/plugin-transform-object-assign --dev` and add the following to your `package.json` under the attribute `babel`:

```
{
    ...
    "babel": {
        "presets": ["react-app"],
        "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign"]
    }
    ...
}
```

or the following to any `babel` configuration file:

```
{
    "presets": ["react-app"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign"]
}
```

This will transform all `Object.assign` so they can be used inside unsupported environments (like IE11).

Ejecting is necessary for this method as facebook has the configurations for their `create-react-app` built-in to provide functioning defaults.